# Casting to a generic base type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I have the following class structure:

```
public class RelationBase : Entity
{
}

public class RelationURL : RelationBase
{
}

public class RelationBaseList<T> where T: RelationBase
{
  public List<T> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class RelationURLList : RelationBaseList<RelationURL>
{
}

public class RefTest
{
  public RelationURLList urlList { get; set; }

  public RefTest()
  {
    urlList = new RelationURList();
    urlList.Collection = new List<RelationUR>();
    urlList.Collection.Add(new RelationUR());
  }
}
```

Via reflection, I get an instance of RelationURLList and I want to cast it to `RelationBaseList<RelationBase>`. Unfortunately, I can only cast it to `RelationBaseList<RelationURL>`

```
RefTest obj = new RefTest();
PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
  object PropertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

  object cast1 = PropertyValue as RelationBaseList<RelationURL>;
  object cast2 = PropertyValue as RelationBaseList<RelationBase>;
}
```

In cast1, I have the expected object, but cast2 is null. As I don't want to cast to each possibly derived class from RelationBase, I want to use the second cast (cast2). Any idea, how I can get the object, without casting to each single derived type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to **do** with the RelationBaseList.Collection?

Using an interface could be a possible solution, if you only want to access the values of the Collection rather than setting them:

```
public interface IRelationBaseList
{
    IEnumerable<RelationBase> Collection { get; }
}

public class RelationBaseList<T> : IRelationBaseList where T : RelationBase
{
    IEnumerable<RelationBase> IRelationBaseList.Collection
    {
        get { return Collection; }
    }
    public List<T> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class RelationURLList : RelationBaseList<RelationURL>
{

}
```

So you can do:

```
RefTest obj = new RefTest();
PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object PropertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

    var relationBaseList = PropertyValue as IRelationBaseList;
    foreach (var relationBase in relationBaseList.Collection)
    { 
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to parse through the collection, so your solution is perfect for me! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The compiler cannot verify that what you're doing is legal.

If `RelationBaseList` was an interface, you could tag the generic parameter with the `out` keyword, to signal that the interface only allows *retrieval* of data from the object.

However, the way your code is organized, the compiler cannot verify that you're not trying to do this:

```
case2.Add(new SomeOtherRelationObject());
```

and the whole point of generics is to make *type-safe* code.

So no, you cannot do that.