# List of generic objects with default constructor

Tags: c#, list, generics, constraints

I just have this simple generic class, which should take T and create one property. If I try to get this property and it does not exists, it should create new instance of this T type and return it. That is why I need to set new() constraint on T.

```
public class ExternalRepository<T> where T : class, IRepositoryable, new()
{
    public IRepositoryable Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (RequestCacheManager.GetAt<T>(typeof(T).Name) == null)
                RequestCacheManager.SetAt<T>(typeof(T).Name, new T());
            return RequestCacheManager.GetAt<T>(typeof(T).Name);
        }
    }
}
```

And now I need to create a list of these. But it looks like it is imposible, because of the new() constraint. I'm need something like this:

```
public static List<ExternalRepository<T>> ExternalRepositories { get; set; } where T : class, IRepositoryable, new()
```

But this is not valid. Could you please help me solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: you can't create generic property, so you can't set constraints for it? try use `method` instead of `property` like `public static List<ExternalRepository<T>> ExternalRepositories<T>() where T : class, IRepositoryable, new()`

Comment: I need to create property. Method is nice, but it just moves this problem inside a method.

Comment: So in this case you can make generic class which contains this property and set constraints for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put, let's say, `ExternalRepository<Person>` and `ExternalRepository<Order>` together in a list, correct?

Sadly, this can't be done explicitly. You'll have to use an interface or base class.

```
public interface IExternalRepository
{
    // declaration of common properties and methods
}

public class ExternalRepository<T> : IExternalRepository
    where T : class, IRepositoryable, new()
{
    // implementation of common properties and methods
    // own properties and methods
}

public static List<IExternalRepository> ExternalRepositories { get; set; }
```

or

```
public class ExternalRepository
{
    // shared properties and methods
}

public class ExternalRepository<T> : ExternalRepository
    where T : class, IRepositoryable, new()
{
    // own properties and methods
}

public static List<ExternalRepository> ExternalRepositories { get; set; }
```

See also my reply to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632568/casting-to-a-generic-base-type/20634137#20634137) question.

Comment: Yes, I also tried List<ExternalRepository<IRepositoryable>>, but this will throw error, because the T type has to have implicit constructor.    THat is why I need somehow set the constraint on list. The error is this: 'ServiceModel.Interface.IRepositoryable' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SSO2.Managers.ExternalRepository<T>'.

Comment: Great, thank you. I was trying to solve it for a long time without pause and I completely overlooked this solution. It looks completely obvious now :-)